# Error Cannot access child value on Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JProperty while reading JSON

Tags: c#, json, .net-core, json.net

I am trying to read the properties from the rest response object. The response is an array of json objects as below. I want to read the properties lastName, titles.investigatorTitle.name, CurrentMembership.currentMembershipType.name

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "investigatorID": 3,
            "firstName": "JH",
            "middleName": "JH",
            "lastName": "HV",
            "titles": [
                {
                    "investigatorTitle": {
                        "id": 7,
                        "name": "Professor",
                        "active": true
                    },
                    "additionalDetails": null,
                    "startDate": null,
                    "endDate": null,
                    "displayIndex": 1
                }
            ],
            "CurrentMembership": [
                {
                    "investigatorCenterMembershipID": 4,
                    "investigatorCenter": {
                        "id": 1,
                        "name": "SCG"
                    },
                    "currentMembershipType": {
                        "id": 11,
                        "name": "ABC Member",
                        "code": "ABC",
                        "active": true
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        {
             "investigatorID": 4,
            "firstName": "FG",
            "middleName": "JH",
            "lastName": "VF",
           "titles": [
                {
                    "investigatorTitle": {
                        "id": 7,
                        "name": "Professor",
                        "active": true
                    },
                    "additionalDetails": null,
                    "startDate": null,
                    "endDate": null,
                    "displayIndex": 1
                }
            ],
            "CurrentMembership": [
                {
                    "investigatorCenterMembershipID": 4,
                    "investigatorCenter": {
                        "id": 1,
                        "name": "SCG"
                    },
                    "currentMembershipType": {
                        "id": 11,
                        "name": "ABC Member",
                        "code": "ABC",
                        "active": true
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "meta": {
        "totalRecords": 675,
        "totalPages": 27
    },
    "links": null
}
```

I am getting the error System.InvalidOperationException: 'Cannot access child value on Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JProperty.' at c.Name = i[0].lastName;

How can I access this correctly?

```
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);

            var InvestigatorList = new List<searchResults>();

            dynamic jsonResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response.Content);


            foreach (dynamic i in jsonResponse)
            {
                Contact c = new Contact();
                
                c.Name = i[0].lastName; //THE ERROR IS HAPPENING HERE

                InvestigatorList.Add(new searchResults()
                {
                    Name = c.Name,
                    Contact = c
                });
                
            }
```

Comment: I don't know the whole code, but you could either build an entire class to reflect JSON structure and then deserialize it to that class. On top of than you would be able to build `InvestigatorList` with linq

Comment: Can you show your searchResults class pls?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this, it was tested in Visual Studio

```
var response = client.Execute(request);

var data = JObject.Parse(response.Content)["data"];
    
List<SearchResults> investigatorList = data.Select(d => new SearchResults { 
Name = (string)d["lastName"], Contact = new Contact {Name = (string)d["lastName"]}}).ToList();
```

result (serialized to json format)

```
[
  {
    "Name": "HV",
    "Contact": {
      "Name": "HV"
    }
  },
  {
    "Name": "VF",
    "Contact": {
      "Name": "VF"
    }
  }
]
```

classes

```
public class Contact
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
public class SearchResults
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Contact Contact { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Nice and simple. There's no need to cast to a `JArray` however.

Comment: @AluanHaddad you are right  Thank you.

Comment: @Serge Thank you so much. It is working.

Comment: "titles": [
                {
                    "investigatorTitle": {
                        "id": 7, "name": "Professor", }, "startDate": null, "endDate": null
                }, {
                    "investigatorTitle": {
                        "id": 8,"name": "Asst Professor" }, "startDate": null, "endDate": null
                }, {
                    "investigatorTitle": {
                        "id": 9, "name": "Researcher" }, "startDate": null, "endDate": "11/11/2021"
                }
            ]

Comment: How can I add titles to the investigator list as a comma delimited string? I want to get all titles where end date is not null. For this example, titles will be Professor, Asst Professor. Titles is a string in my class.

Comment: @may Fix the json by adding { } in the beginnig and end,  and try this code --  var titlesParsed= (JArray)JObject.Parse(json)["titles"];   
var titles= string.Join(", ", titlesParsed.Where(p=> string.IsNullOrEmpty((string) p["endDate"])).Select(p => p["investigatorTitle"] ["name"].ToString()).ToArray());

Comment: @Serge Thanks again. This worked for me

Answer (score 2):

Ok im not sure what you doing, cause it's a method im not familiar with.
what i do with newtonsoft is i build classes to reflect Json Format. And then deserialize it onto it.

**Class:**

```
public class DeserializeJson
{
    public DataList ExtractedData;
    public DeserializeJson(IRestResponse response)
    {
        try
        {
            ExtractedData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataList>(response.Content);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(ex.Message());
        }
    }
    
    public class DataList
    {
        public List<Data> Data {get; set;}
        public meta meta {get; set;}
        public string? links {get;set;}
    }
    public class Data
    {
        public int investigatorID {get; set;}
        public string firstName {get; set;}
        public string middleName {get; set;}
        public string lastName {get; set;}
        public List<titles> titles {get; set;}
        public List<CurrentMembership> {get; set;}
    }
    public class meta
    {
        public int totalRecords {get; set;}
        public int totalPages {get; set;}
    }
    public class CurrentMembership
    {
        public int investigatorCenterMembershipID {get; set;}
        public investigatorCenter investigatorCenter {get; set;}
        public currentMembershipType currentMembershipType {get; set;}
    }
    public class titles
    {
        public int investigatorID {get; set;}
        //not sure what additionalDetails could also hold but you have to reflect it
        public bool additionalDetails {get; set;}
        public DateTime? startDate {get; set;}
        public DateTime? endDate {get; set;}
        public int displayIndex {get; set;}
        public investigatorTitle investigatorTitle{get;set;}
    }
    public class investigatorTitle
    {
        public int id {get; set;}
        public string name {get; set;}
        public bool active {get; set;}
    }
    public class currentMembershipType
    {
        public int id {get; set;}
        public string name {get; set;}
    }
    public class investigatorCenter
    {
        public int id {get; set;}
        public string name {get; set;}
        public string code {get; set;}
        public bool active {get; set;}
    }
}
```

After that i would pass whatever you want as everything there is accessible with linq.

For insance:

**Access:**

```
    //deserialize
    DeserializeJson jsonResponse = new DeserializeJson(response);
    
    //access excample
    List<string> InvestigatorList = jsonResponse.ExtractedData.Data.Select(name=>name.lastName).ToList();
```